# Is it safe to assume non-undefined state of component property if it gets its value synchronously in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript

It's a very basic question, so I indeed have been trying to seek the answer to it in SO, but it's eluded me in some arcane way.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `{{bar.length}}`,
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  bar: string;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bar = 'foo';
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is nothing more than a *synchronous* initialization of the variable `bar` inside the `ngOnInit()` method. The component's template assumes that the `bar` is not `undefined` and does not use an elvis operator (`{{bar?.length}}`).

I know it's all a bad practice to omit `undefined`-checking as long as we get a varable value through some *asynchronous* things (`subscribe()` and so on), but is it OK in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a good practice to initialize your properties (`@Input`s or not). This way, you can guarantee that they will have values when the template is rendered, if a parent component does not pass anything at first.

The way your code is written right now wouldn't really cause an error in the template because you only change `bar`'s value in `onInit` and nowhere else. However, down the line, your code might become more complex and `bar` might become "empty" (`null` or `undefined`) at some point. If you don't remember to put a guard in your template, it might throw an error during runtime. So it's a good practice to first make sure that a variable exists before you call any of its properties in the template.

In a nutshell: it's OK to leave it as it is right now, but it's safer if you put some guards in the template to avoid any future runtime errors.